# Python output format

Tags: python, format

When I am printing the following informatiom It looks really ugly. 
The text display is very long and you cannot really read it.

Code:

```
import psutil
print("Disk: ", psutil.disk_partitions())
```

The output I get is:

```
Disk:  [sdiskpart(device='C:\\', mountpoint='C:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,fixed'), sdiskpart(device='D:\\', mountpoint='D:\\', fstype='', opts='cdrom'), sdiskpart(device='E:\\', mountpoint='E:\\', fstype='', opts='cdrom'), sdiskpart(device='F:\\', mountpoint='F:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,fixed'), sdiskpart(device='H:\\', mountpoint='H:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,removable')]
```

In one long line! Is there a way to filter the output or display it on multiple lines?

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`psutil.disk_partitinos()`](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.disk_partitions) gives you a list of partitions on your systme.

Each element in that list is instance of [`sdiskpart`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/08964b08700fcfc5a4917a01107009a3ee913341/psutil/_common.py#L204) which is a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) with the following properties:

```
['count', 'device', 'fstype', 'index', 'mountpoint', 'opts']
```

You *will have to* process this list and format and display it the way you *want* using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter) and [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print).

Please refer to the [psutil](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/) documentation.

A simple function that displays "disk information" in a "better way" could be something as simple as:

**Example:**

```
from psutil import disk_partitions


def diskinfo():
    for i, disk in enumerate(disk_partitions()):
        print "Disk #{0:d} {1:s}".format(i, disk.device)
        print " Mount Point: {0:s}".format(disk.mountpoint)
        print " File System: {0:s}".format(disk.fstype)
        print " Options: {0:s}".format(disk.opts)


diskinfo()
```

**Output:**

```
bash-4.3# python /app/foo.py
Disk #0 /dev/mapper/docker-8:1-2762733-bdb0f27645efd726d69c77d0cd856d6218da5783b2879d9a83a797f8b896b4be
 Mount Point: /
 File System: ext4
 Options: rw,relatime,discard,stripe=16,data=ordered
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
print("Disks:")
for disk in psutil.disk_partitions()):
    print(disk)
```

That should look like this:

```
Disks:
sdiskpart(device='C:\\', mountpoint='C:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,fixed')
sdiskpart(device='D:\\', mountpoint='D:\\', fstype='', opts='cdrom')
sdiskpart(device='E:\\', mountpoint='E:\\', fstype='', opts='cdrom')
sdiskpart(device='F:\\', mountpoint='F:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,fixed')
sdiskpart(device='H:\\', mountpoint='H:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,removable')
```